# How do you put arrows in the x-axis label of a Matlab plot?

Tags: matlab

E.g something like below (I'd like a <-- arrow pointing in one direction, and a --> arrow pointing in another).

I'd also like it to be close to publication-quality, so simply using --> probably wouldn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the last versions of Matlab you can use the function **annotation()** to create some annotation objects in the figure (such as arrows).

The following example, extracted from the documentation, adds a text arrow to the graph by defining the text arrow to start from (0.3,0.6) and extend to (0.5,0.5) in normalized figure coordinates:

```
figure
plot(1:10);
annotation('textarrow', [0.3,0.5], [0.6,0.5],'String' , 'Straight Line');
```

[image]

More info: [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code on the MATLAB File Exchange: [arrow.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow-m).  I just tried it out, and it is pretty neat.  You can draw arrows using the mouse by simply calling the function

```
arrow
```

and then dragging the mouse icon across the plot to draw the arrow from its start to end position.

Or supply start and stop coordinates for the arrow as

```
arrow([100 50],[300 200],'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','r')
```

which will draw the arrow in red.